# Python Tkinter Login Functionality through lists

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for the first time and am trying to create login functionality so that a user's password and username are both checked correctly. The difficulty I'm having is iterating through a *for loop* and producing one "INVALID USER" comment instead of one for every incorrect user - I need to create a message box or label that appears to tell the user incorrect details have been inputted, otherwise they are correct and can login without any issues.

All usernames and passwords have first been created with SQLite3 and then mapped to a student class. Here is the relevant code for the GUI:

```
    self.password_entry = tk.Entry(width="25", borderwidth="3", relief="sunken")
    self.password_entry.place(relx=0.83, rely=0.39, anchor="e")
    self.user_entry = tk.Entry(width="25", borderwidth="3", relief="sunken")
    self.user_entry.place(relx=0.83, rely=0.35, anchor="e")

    def check_user(self):

    for student in students:
        if student.username == self.user_entry.get() and student.password == self.password_entry.get():
            print("VALID USER")
            break
        else:
            print("INVALID USER")
```

Unless I enter the username and password of the first instance of the Student class, it will print "INVALID USER" until it finds the correct student.

Is there a way to prevent this so that code will only appear if the user details are incorrect? Otherwise they are fine and can login without any error message appearing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a boolean before your for loop that indicates whether the match was found (to initialize it, it should be false since you haven't found the valid user yet). In the loop, when you find the match and print the valid user message, set the boolean to True. Then after the for loop check if the boolean is false and only print the message then:

```
validUser = False
for student in students:
    if student.username == self.user_entry.get() and student.password == self.password_entry.get():
        print("VALID USER")
        validUser = True
        break
if not validUser:
    print("INVALID USER")
```

Comment: Thanks Aly! Not sure why I didn't think of that but it works exactly how I want it to!